# Show that if $f(x, y, z)$ satisfies Laplace's equation, then $\iint_S f \nabla f \cdot \hat{n} \ dS = \iiint_E |\nabla f|^2 \ dV$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

**Problem**

> Show that if $f(x, y, z)$ satisfies Laplace's equation, then $\iint_S f \nabla f \cdot \hat{n} \ dS = \iiint_E |\nabla f|^2 \ dV$, where $S$ is the boundary of the volume $V$.

---

**Solution**

The divergence theorem is $\iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \hat{n} \ dS = \iiint_V \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} \ dV$.

Let $\mathbf{F} = f \nabla f$. Then

$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = \nabla \cdot (f\nabla f)$

$= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\left(f \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} \right) + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{y}}\left(f \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} \right) + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\left(f \dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}} \right)$

$= f\dfrac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}} + \left(\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} \right)^2 + f\dfrac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{y^2}} + \left(\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}} \right)^2 + f\dfrac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{z^2}} + \left(\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}} \right)^2$

$= f \nabla^2 f + |\nabla f|^2 = |\nabla f|^2$, since $\nabla^2 f \equiv f_{xx} + f_{yy} + f_{zz} = 0$.

---

I understood everything in the solution up until $= f \nabla^2 f + |\nabla f|^2$. Where did the absolute value signs in $|\nabla f|^2$ come from?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla f$ is a 3-dimensional vector. The book uses $|\nabla f|$ to mean the norm of this vector. They could have written $\nabla f \cdot\nabla f$ instead of $|\nabla f|^2$

One has
$$|\nabla f| = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where did the norm come from? I don't see anything that resembles a norm in the preceding expressions?

Comment: See my edit above. The square of the euclidian norm is the scalar product of the vector with itself.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks you very much for the assistance.